# Sending my first message on the slack API

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I registered my first app, and it looks like this:
[image]

All of the fields are populated below the screen shot.

Now, I have some basic python code using the examples found on [their repo](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient).

I create the following test script:

```
import traceback
app_id = 'FAKE.VALUE'
client_id = 'FAKE.VALUE'
client_secret = 'FAKE.VALUE'
signin_secret = 'FAKE.VALUE'
verification_token = 'FAKE.VALUE'

items = locals()

import os
import slack

items = locals().copy()

for k in items:

    if '__' not in k:
        val = items[k]

        try:
            client = slack.WebClient(token=val)

            response = client.chat_postMessage(
                channel='CE476K9HT',
                text='Hello-----' + str(val))

            print(response)
        except:
            print(k)
            traceback.print_exc()
            print('-'*50)
```

But all of the responses I get say:

```
The server responses with: {'ok':False,'error':'invalid_auth'}
```

For some reason, is it necessary to use path variables?

It is unclear to me what type of auth is required here.

---

After doing what Erik suggested,

[image]

I have a `xoxp` code and registered the redirect url to `http://localhost`.

and added the following scopes:
[image]

and updated my code to look like:

```
oauth_token ='xoxp-*****************'

import os
import slack

items = locals().copy()

client = slack.WebClient(token=oauth_token)

response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel='my_channel_id',
    text='Hello-----')
```

I got my channel ID from the url:

```
https://app.slack.com/client/FOO/my_channel_id
```

When I run my code, I get the following back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/git/slack_messaging/slack_messaging.py", line 20, in <module>
    text='Hello-----')
  File "/home/usr/git/python-slackclient/slack/web/client.py", line 382, in chat_postMessage
    return self.api_call("chat.postMessage", json=kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/git/python-slackclient/slack/web/base_client.py", line 172, in api_call
    return self._event_loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/home/usr/anaconda2/envs/beer/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 573, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/usr/git/python-slackclient/slack/web/base_client.py", line 241, in _send
    return SlackResponse(**{**data, **res}).validate()
  File "/home/usr/git/python-slackclient/slack/web/slack_response.py", line 176, in validate
    raise e.SlackApiError(message=msg, response=self)
slack.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'missing_scope', 'needed': 'chat:write:user', 'provided': 'admin,identify'}
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things to make your script work.

## 1. OAuth token

You need a valid OAuth token and provide it when initializing the Slack Client:

```
client = slack.WebClient(token="xoxb-xxx")
```

To get a token you need to install your Slack app to a workspace. You can do that on the app management page under "Install App". Your OAuth token will also be displayed on that page once you installed it.

## 2. Permissions

Your Oauth Token / Slack app needs to have the permission to post messages. On the app management pages go to "OAuth & permission" and add the needed permission to your app:. e.g. [chat:write:user](https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write:user) for user tokens.

Note that you need to reinstall your app every time to add a permission.